# converting different date formats into a single unique date format in mysql

Tags: regex

example ;like 22-1-1994
              2/12/1995
              3.5.1997
              14-july-1996 to convert various date formats into a single unique date format like

example;   14-july-1996

Comment: It might be a better idea to do a one-time script to fix all the dates in one go. Then use code to convert any new dates into the right format. I'm not too familiar with MySQL though, so I can't help on the specifics.

Comment: I can however help with a regex that just gets the relevant parts from any of those listed formats. Would you like me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[`^(?:(\d\d?)([-\/.])(\d\d?)\2(\d{4})|(\d\d?)-(\w+)-(\d{4}))$`](https://regex101.com/r/iT5rO4/1)

This assumes each date is on its own in a text field. And it only finds the values for the provided formats specifically. It also does no validation (it's possible to do, but would be a much more complex regex, so it's better done in whatever language you're using to normalize these into regular timestamps). And the text months would have to be sorted out in code, also.

Comment: If you'd like an explanation of how the regex works, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

thank u,, actually it did not worked for my problem to solve,,,actually i want date format in (11-11-2011) like this format only....from various date inputs form diffirent date formats like (11/11/2011),(12:11:2012),(12-augest-2010) ;;